# How do I run a file on localhost from an html page?

Tags: javascript, python, html, localhost

I have an HTML file that reads the next event in my calendar using this Google Calendar API javascript . (https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/js).

It works correctly as described in the above link by manually inserting http://localhost:8000/quickstart.html in a browser address window with a python webserver running locally and I can see it makes a GET request in the Python server window. The events are printed to the same browser window. I have the quickstart.html file in the Python 3 directory.

The question is how to run it (or the scripts inside) automatically from my menu.html page which refreshes once a minute with the time and date and print the event in the menu?

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. This is a small internal system all running on the same Windows 7 PC so there are no security worries in case that's an issue. Thanks, Phil

Comment: Are you asking how to run `quickstart.html` inside of `menu.html` on a time interval?

Answer (score 0):

If the code you are talking about runs on page load you could add
`setInterval(function(){ location.reload(); }, 6000);`
to your javascript or
`<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="60">`
to your HTML either will refresh the page the page every 60 seconds automatically and thus run your code again.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I already have the menu page refreshing exactly as you suggest with the refresh command. It's how to run the scripts in quickstart.html from the menu page which is escaping me.  I've tried things like <a href = "http;//localhost:8000/quickstart.html"/a> in the menu page but that doesn't seem to do anything,

Comment: I think I may have found a solution with iFrames. <iframe  src="http://localhost:8000/readcalendar.html" align="left" frameborder="0">
 </iframe>

Comment: That is an ok solution. as I don't have access to your code to see how it runs I would also consider looking into 'jquery load'.

Comment: The code for quickstart.html (I renamed it readcalendar.html in the last  post to try and make it clearer) is available in the link in my first post. There is nothing currently in my menu.html other than the iframe link.

Comment: The Iframe is doing all I need so I will stick with that, thanks.